How to call title of Tool Strip Menu Item in Visual Studio (C#)
I'm trying to make a really basic word processor program in Visual Studio 2022 for a class I'm taking. One of the features I want to include is the ability to change the font of the document via some tool strip menu items (which for expedience I will refer to as "font buttons") at the top. I've made a click event method connected to each of the font buttons, and I want it to call upon the text of the font button and use it to change the font of the document(txtDocument). However, I am struggling to get it to correctly retrieve the text.
For reference, here is my code:
private void fontButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call upon button clicked
    ToolStripMenuItem fontBtn = new ToolStripMenuItem();
    
    //change fontName text to name of button clicked
    fontName = fontBtn.Text.ToString();
    
    //change font of txtDocument to title of clicked button
    txtDocument.Font = new Font(fontName, fontSize);
   
    //test code to make sure the right font is retrieved
    txtDocument.Text = fontName;
}

Right now, instead of fontName changing to the text of the font button, it just sets fontName blank. I'm still somewhat new to coding, so I am certain there is something very basic I am missing.

The first line within your function is initializing a new empty menu item. You might want sender as ToolStripMenuItem instead...

Which line are you referring to, AKX?

Required reading: new operator (C# reference)  You are creating a new ToolStripMenuItem (hence the clever name).  It will not be the ToolStripMenuItem` already on the form, so it wont have any text at all...it's new.

In the fontButton_Click event, the sender is the ToolStripButton:
private void fontButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //call upon button clicked
    if (sender is not ToolStripButton fontBtn) return;

    //change fontName text to name of button clicked
    var fontName = fontBtn.Text!;

    //change font of txtDocument to title of clicked button
    txtDocument.Font = new Font(fontName, txtDocument.Font.Size);

    //test code to make sure the right font is retrieved
    txtDocument.Text = fontName;
}


Thanks for the help. I've found that replacing "New ToolStripMenuItem()" with "sender as ToolStripMenuItem()" makes it work. Thank you to AKX for making the suggestion.
